# string from after the second space character

Tags: c++, string

I have a string

```
string str= "Jhon 12345 R333445 3434";
string str1= "Mike 00987 #F54543";
```

So from str i want `"R333445 3434"` only because after second space character whatever appear i want all, similarly form `str1 "#F54543"`

I used stringstream and extract the next word after the space but it wont give correct result for

```
str ="Jhon 12345 R333445 3434";
```

it gives R333445 only it should give `"R333445 3434"`

Please suggest some better logic of my problem.

Comment: You should give actual code examples of what you have tried.

Comment: How can we find the bug in code you haven't shown us?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  const std::string str = "Jhon 12345 R333445 3434";

  size_t pos = str.find(" ");
  if (pos == std::string::npos)
    return -1;

  pos = str.find(" ", pos + 1);
  if (pos == std::string::npos)
    return -1;

  std::cout << str.substr(pos, std::string::npos);
}
```

**Output**

```
 R333445 3434
```

According to http://ideone.com/P1Knbe.

Comment: What do you do it str.find fails, returns npos, and you add one to it?

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann I was asking about str.find and correct usage, since if find fails to find you add one and get problems.

Comment: @2501 the doc (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/) says: "If this is greater than the string length, the function never finds matches." I do not see the problem.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann *If no matches were found, the function returns string::npos.* npos is defined as the maximum value size_t can hold. What happens when you add a small number to npos?

Comment: @2501 Updated again, feel free to update yourself too.

Comment: You see, I'm not a C++ expert, so I was trying to get some guidance. That problem bothered me and I was curious.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65364/discussion-between-micha-wiedenmann-and-2501).

Answer (score 2):

It seems you want to skip the first two words and read the rest, if that is correct you can do something like this.

```
std::string str("Jhon 12345 R333445 3434"");
std::string tmp, rest;

std::istringstream iss(str);
// Read the first two words.    
iss >> tmp >> tmp;
// Read the rest of the line to 'rest'
std::getline(iss,rest);
std::cout << rest;
```

Comment: yes somewhat i want the same neglect the first two words and read the rest.

Answer (score 1):

You could find the index of the second space and then take the substring from one position past it to the end.

```
int index = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i){
    index = (str.find(" ", index)) + 1;
}

ans = str.substr(index);
```

[reference on std::string::find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/)

[reference on std::string::substr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/)